# css :last-child not affecting my last element

Tags: css

I have the following [example](https://codepen.io/adviner/pen/mdVRreP) where the last  doesn't seem to work when using :last-child.  In my code, you can see when I refer to the last element using the class "aa" it is showing the "+ Add"

```
&.aa {}
```

But if I comment out

```
&.aa{}
```

and set it to

```
&:last-child{}
```

the "+ Add" on the last

is not showing up.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because **you have a typo in your HTML structure**.

So your current structure is like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <div>
      Tom Hanks
      <br /> Jenny Hanks
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item active">
    <div>
      Henry Fonda
      <br /> Valarie White
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="aa">
    &nbsp;
  </li>
<ul>
```

As we can see **you didn't close the `ul` element properly**, so the last child of it will not consider as:

```html
<li class="aa">
   &nbsp;
</li>
```

and it will ignore this element as last-child, so `&:last-child` won't work as expected.
All you need to do is to close your elements properly.

So it should be something like this:

```
<ul>
  <!--> ul inner elements <-->
</ul>
```

**Live demo**: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/jOWyJJB)